# How to create a border below text that does not go longer than that text?

Tags: layout, ms-word

E.g.,

http://img862.imageshack.us/img862/931/73853515.png

The border below the text is too long to the left by a few points (the dotted line is just for illustration).

Many thanks!

[Note: I have also posted this question into [Mircosoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/how-to-create-a-border-below-text-that-does-not-go/76e149d6-e44f-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5), but I am not sure how active that site is...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in Microsoft Word (which is what I assume from the tags) you can put TEST in a table (i.e. in a single cell), enable only the bottom border (at which point you will have the situation you have above, where the black bottom border does not align with T).

In order to make the bottom border align with the T, right-click the table and go to Table Properties > Table > Options and set the Left 'Default Cell Margin' to 0cm.